# Can I filter out spam based on it containing Chinese characters?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention

I regularly get spam email that has tons of what I assume are Chinese characters in it.  Is there a way to setup Outlook to redirect any mail with these types of characters into my spam folder?

Comment: There are thousands of Chinese characters, so creating a rule for all of them could be problematic. I doubt Outlook would let you filter all unicode characters between 0x4e00 and 0x9fff either! Consider an upstream spam blocker with your ISP?

Comment: I blocked everything but US-ASCII and Western European. I still get Asian spam but much less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Outlook (2003, 2007, 2010) you can block mails with "unfamiliar characters", based on their Encodings.

- [Outlook 2003 Junk E-mail Filter](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/about-the-junk-e-mail-filter-HP005242967.aspx)
  Open the "Junk E-mail Filter Lists" section, International List, Blocked Encodings List
- [Outlook 2007 Junk E-mail Filter - Block messages in unfamiliar alphabets](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/add-names-to-the-junk-e-mail-filter-lists-HA001230163.aspx#BM5)
- [Outlook 2010 Junk E-mail Filter - Block messages in unfamiliar alphabets](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/add-names-to-the-junk-e-mail-filter-lists-HA010355043.aspx#_Toc257134910)

From the Outlook 2007 Junk E-Mail Filter section ...

> ### Block messages in unfamiliar alphabets
>
> You can block all e-mail addresses in
>   language encodings (also known as
>   character sets, or alphabets) that you
>   specify. Today, most junk e-mail is
>   sent in the US-ASCII encoding. The
>   remainder is sent in various other
>   international encodings. The Blocked
>   Encodings List lets you filter out
>   unwanted e-mail that is displayed in
>   languages that you don't understand.
>
> 1. On the Tools menu, click Options to open the Options dialog box.
> 2. On the Preferences tab, under E-mail, click Junk E-mail to open the Junk E-mail Options dialog box.
> 3. Click the International tab, and then click Blocked Encodings List.
> 4. In the list, click the language encoding that you want to block, or click Select All.
> 5. Click OK twice.