# Spam emails in a business Netwok

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, anti-virus, webserver

We have a network server in our business and all the stuff use outlook 2010 for our communication. We also have a company email and each employee has his own company email. Two days now the employees receive spam emails each other. I downloaded Panda Antivirus in all the computers but we have the same problem yet. What else can I do?

Comment: You said you installed and ran antivirus on all computers, does that include the server?

Comment: Except server!!!

Comment: You need to protect the server too! No matter how clean each PC is becomes irrelevant if the server is infected with viruses or malware/spyware. The entire network is possibly compromised.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the emails are coming from inside your network?

First of all I would track the messages through your mail server to determine where they are coming form (you should be able to get an IP address) which will tell you either the machine inside your network that is causing the problem or that they are coming from outside your network.

If they are coming from inside you can address that problem machine with an AV scan or rebuild.

If they are coming from outside you can change your settings on your mail server so it does not accept mail from other servers claiming to be from your domain. If you Google your mailserver and "restrict incoming mails from my domain" you could probably find a good walkthrough.

As you are on Exchange 2010 the article below tells you how to stop your domain accepting emails FROM your own domain when the sender isn't authenticated. Please bear in mind that if you have programs sending via your exchange without authentication then you will need to set up a second receive connector for them or configure them for authentication before making this change.
http://exchangepedia.com/2008/09/how-to-prevent-annoying-spam-from-your-own-domain.html

It is also worth configuring SPF as this will prevent spammers from pretending to be you to other people (very bad if they do this with your actual clients!). Link below details how to do this.
https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/658/How+can+I+create+an+SPF+record+for+my+domain%3F#gs

Comment: The most of them are coming from inside the network I think...Because the spams are like employeename@ourbusinessname.com. Furthermore we receive spams from employees who are not working now in the company but they have company's emails.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily mean the email is coming from inside the network, it could be coming from outside your network (from a normal spam server) claiming to be from your domain. This is the most likely and common cause of emails like this, the company I work for receives them regularly.
If you check the header information in the email it may give accurate information about where the email came from or as its spam it may not.

Comment: The most of them as I show contain chinese characters (with smileys etc). I found a small solution here  http://superuser.com/questions/269561/can-i-filter-out-spam-based-on-it-containing-chinese-characters

Comment: This will stop you receiving some of the spam but still leaves you vulnerable to better crafted spam claiming to be from internal users. Such spam is a higher risk as users are more likely to trust it. I would strongly recommend limiting your mail server so it will only accept emails from your domain from authorised sources. I am afraid without know the type of mailserver being used I cant point you to the right walkthrough for how to do this.

Comment: The type is IMAP (if you mean this)

Comment: Does "sending" through your company SMTP server requires username/password, or "anyone" can send mail using your company SMTP? (Might want to check that)

Comment: I mean what type of mailserver, Exchange2007? Exchange2010? or some other mail server?

Comment: Oh Ok...Exchange 2010!!

Comment: My addition to the answer above contains a link to a site detailing how to do this. I would strongly recommend this and as a side note setting up SPF records is probably a good idea too! (Another link I'll add to the answer in a second)