# Spam-tag chinese spam mails via ISPConfig

Tags: email, isp, spam-prevention

I'm looking for a way to get rid of the ton of - I assume - Chinese spam mails I get every day.

**Is there a way to filter out mails which contain Asian characters in the subject?**

I googled [around](https://superuser.com/q/269561/138877) but I couldn't [find](https://superuser.com/questions/732443/blocking-or-filtering-chinese-spam-using-postfix) a solution for `ISPConfig`.

Thanks,
Ron